# Implementing Neumann boundary condition for elasticity problem using the finite element method

Tags: finite-element, boundary-conditions

I am solving the following mixed boundary elasticity problem with the finite element method on the unit circle, using a triangle mesh with 3 nodes on each element. In my problem I know $u_1$  and $t_2$:

[image: problem given]

With the following weak form:

$$\int_\Omega \sum_{i,j}^2 \sigma_{ij}(u) \epsilon_{ij}(v)= \int_\tau v_2 t_2 $$

I have already implemented it correctly for the pure Dirichlet problem. (so the global stiffness matrix is also good for this problem), but I do something wrong when implementing the Neumann boundary condition and I cannot figure out what. (I still get the right solution for $u_1$ where I have the Dirichlet condition). On the right side of the picture is the fem solution and on the left side is the analytical one:

[image: solution representation]

This is what I do when implementing the Neumann boundary condition:

I go over each triangular element:

- I extract the coordinates of each node of the element:
  $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), (x_3, y_3)$
  (the elements are numbered in anticlockwise sense)
- if $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are on the boundary:

  - I calculate the outward unit normal:
    $$ n2=\frac{x_1-x_2}{\sqrt{(y_2-y_1)^2+(x_1-x_2)^2}} $$
  - I update the force vector F in the place corresponding to $C_e^12$ and $C_e^22$ ($v_2=\sum_{B=1}^3 N^BC_e^B2$) by adding :
    $$ 0.5 \sigma_0 n_2 \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$$
- if $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_3,y_3)$ are on the boundary:

  - $n2=\frac{x_3-x_1}{\sqrt{(y_1-y_3)^2 + (x_3-x_1)^2}}$
  - update with
    $ -0.5 \sigma_0 n_2 \sqrt{(x_3-x_1)^2 + (y_3-y_1)^2} $
- if $(x_2,y_2)$ and $(x_3,y_3)$ are on the boundary:

  - $ n2=\frac{x_2-x_3}{\sqrt{(y_3-y_2)^2+(x_2-x_3)^2}} $
  - update with:
    $ 0.5 \sigma_0 n_2 \sqrt{(x_3-x_2)^2 + (y_3-y_2)^2} $

Comment: You show the same domain for both the Neumann and the Dirichlet BC. Does that mean your problem has either a Dirichlet BC prescribed over the entire boundary OR a Neumann BC over the entire boundary? If so, in the Neumann case, there is no unique solution; the finite element equations are singular in that case. A Dirichlet condition has to be prescribed at one point or some other constraint applied to make the solution unique.

Comment: I have Dirichlet for x  (u1) and Neumann for y (t2), 1 is for x and 2 is for y

Comment: I believe that is not a well-posed problem. Specifically, there is no constraint to prevent the body from undergoing rigid body translation in the y-direction. Are you sure you are not getting some kind of error or warning indicator from your equation solution function?

Comment: In this case I should solve it separately for y like I would do for a pure Neumann problem? with lagrange multiplier for example

Comment: I couldn't immediately tell from your post but I assume that you have a set of self-equilbrating stresses in the y direction (i.e. they sum to zero). You could use a Lagrange multiplier to add the single necessary constraint. Or, even simpler, you can constrain the y-displacement at a single node. If, after solution, you calculate the value of the reaction force at that node, it should be close to zero. Or, if you use a Lagrange multiplier constraint, its value should be close to zero.That is, if your stress boundary conditions are in equilibrium, no constraint force should be required.